# EXCEL 2010 MACRO Concatenate cells that have different number of rows included

Tags: excel, rows, vba

I have like 10 excel files with more than 10K rows each one.

I would like to concatenate a description field that has been broken into different rows. Some records have two rows, some have 3 rows and some of them even have 5 or 6 rows each!, every record have a single   row with a unique code or line number.

I've tried with nested if functions but it gets too complicated when it comes to determine when a record have 4 or more rows.

The file looks like this:

```
  A         B
CODIGO   DESCRIPCIÓN

R2       Dos Renglones
         2R, Renglón Dos
R3       Tres Renglones
         3R, Renglón 2
         3R, Renglón 3
R4       Cuatro Renglones
         4R, Renglón 2
         4R, Renglón 3
         4R, Renglón 4
R5       Cinco Renglones
         5R Renglón 2
         5R Renglón 3
         5R Renglón 4
         5R Renglón 5
R21      Dos Renglones
         2R, Renglón Dos
R51      Cinco Renglones
         5R Renglón 2
         5R Renglón 3
         5R Renglón 4
         5R Renglón 5
R31      Tres Renglones
         3R, Renglón 2
         3R, Renglón 3
```

Is there a series of formulas or a macro I can use to achieve these?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code :

```
Sub sample()


    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim CellA As String
    Dim CellB As String

    For i = 2 To lastRow
        CellA = IIf(Cells(i, 1) = "", CellA, Cells(i, 1))
        CellB = Cells(i, 2)
        Cells(i, 3) = CellA & " " & CellB
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

**Updated code**

```
Sub sample()


    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim firstCell As Boolean
    Dim dataCell As Range
    Dim strVal As String

    For i = 2 To lastRow

        If Cells(i, 1) <> vbNullString Then
begin:
            If firstCell = False Then
                Set dataCell = Cells(i, 1)
                firstCell = True

                strVal = vbNullString
                strVal = Cells(i, 2)

            Else

                Cells(dataCell.Row, 3) = strVal
                firstCell = False
                GoTo begin
            End If



        Else
            strVal = strVal & ", " & Cells(i, 2)
        End If


    Next

      Cells(dataCell.Row, 3) = strVal
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, but I think that wasn't what I was looking for, the concatenated value I wanted in return for the first series R2 is:
in a single cell the value "Dos Renglones 2R, Renglón Dos"
for the following case R3 : "Tres renglones 3R, Renglón 2 3R, Renglón 3" and not with the code included.

But you already gave me a hint on how to proceed. Thanks Again.

Comment: @Sitmex Pls copy the updated code. I hope its what you are looking for.

Comment: That was it! thank you very much. exactly what I was looking for, saved me like 50 work hours... literally.